# how to post jsonarray using volley library

Tags: android

I am Working on Google Volley Library. I am Doing Other Stuff Nicely But I Wanted to do a `Post method` with `JsonArray` to the `PHP Server`, but I don't Know how to do it.

They don't provide any documentation for hot to use volley library, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post that part of code where you got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Here look for `JsonArrayRequest` for an example 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

EDIT:You can use the standard `JsonObjectRequest` to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonArrayRequest` doesn't have POST method. You have to change `JsonArrayRequest` constructor.

change this

```
public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }
```

to this

```
 public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener, errorListener);
    }
```

After this change, you can use POST method as JsonObjectRequest class

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a JSONArray as param with volley library I implemented this class called JSONPostArrayRequest, which extends JSONRequest:

```
public class JsonPostArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {

    JSONArray params;
    public JsonPostArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,JSONArray params) {
        super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
        this.params=params;
    }

     @Override
     public byte[] getBody()  {
            if ( this.params != null && this.params.length() > 0) {
                return encodeParameters( this.params, getParamsEncoding());
            }
            return null;

      }

     private byte[] encodeParameters(JSONArray params, String paramsEncoding) {
            try {
                return params.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String jsonString =
                        new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert **JsonObject** or **JsonArray** to encoded string and call this method.

```
@Override
 public byte[] getBody()  {

   return encodedString;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

To send `JSONArray` to a PHP server using `POST` request:

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
final String URL = "your-API-url.php";
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray> () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        // Handle response
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Handle error
    }
});

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
mRequestQueue.(req);
```

Comment: but how to post parameters in it